# In an SN1 reaction, 1-bromohexane reacts with NaOH, but would the Na or H be the nucleophile that substitutes the Bromine?

Tags: organic-chemistry

The answer says that the Bromine would be replaced with OH and NaBr would be formed, along with CH3(CH2)4CH2OH, but why? Does it have to do with stability? And if so, how does the OH replacing Br make the product more stable? Thanks.

Comment: 1-bromohexane does not SN1

Comment: NaOH doesn't do SN1

Answer (score 1):

SN1 is very less likely to be followed in 1-bromohexane, rather a SN2 pathway will be followed. OH- replaces Br as Br- as Br is a good leaving group. This has nothing to do with product stability. The haloalkane substrate is reactive so it reacts, as simple as that.